# Is there a minimum running configuration for OS X?

Tags: macos

I'd like to run just the bare essentials in Lion while I read up on what is new, where the docs are, and how to lock it down.

Is there a base set or 'stripped down' list of apps that I could run while adding more as I see fit?

EDIT:  8GB Ram, core 2 duo LP64 Kernel. Before I asked this question I installed 2x, over top of Snow Leopard, then on a clean drive.

### One of the solutions:

I did the NVRAM, the SMC, single user fsck, bootstrapped launchd, dumped memory ( the diagnostic tools *are* nice. )

Hardware and memory checked out fine.  Oddly, it did not even show a lot of load. That's quite odd because the fans blast spin up and then POP ... kernel panic. Full speed for hours.  But I found the culprit:

```
Jul 29 09:58:48 8va com.apple.mdworker.pool.0[177]: PSSniffer error: No such file or directory
/serveradmin
Jul 29 13:59:04 8va mds[83]: (/)(Warning) IndexQuery in bool preIterate_FSI(SISearchCtx_FSI*):Throttling inefficient file system query
Jul 29 13:59:19: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul 29 13:59:19 8va Firewall[112]: *** process 112 exceeded 500 log message per second limit  -  remaining messages this second discarded ***
Jul 29 13:59:24 8va servermgrd[77]: servermgr_ipfilter:ipfw config:Notice:Flushed IPv4 rules
```

**I had servermgrd from the very beginning.  You get *more* services with server app, not *some*. Flush the ruleset? Why not? Process clearly had something to say!**

```
Jul 29 13:59:24 8va servermgrd[77]: servermgr_ipfilter:ipfw config:Notice:Flushed IPv6 rules
Jul 29 13:59:31 8va com.apple.loginwindow[85]: 8va
Jul 29 14:00:49 8va Safari[204]: Failed to write public plist to URL file://localhost/Users/kb/Library/Saved%20Application%20State/com.apple.Safari.s
```

**Really, the menu option to restore windows was quite sufficient. It saves iTerm states too. Why would I want this? Rebooting means something went wrong, I want to wake up from the nightmare, not relive it.**

`Jul 29 14:00:52 8va su[390]: kb to root on /dev/ttys001`

**Thats me noticing the abrupt fan speed increase.**

```
Jul 29 14:01:00 8va mds[83]: (/)(Warning) IndexQuery in bool preIterate_FSI(SISearchCtx_FSI*):Throttling inefficient file system query
Jul 29 14:02:30 8va ipfw[290]:  limit 1000 reached on entry 12300
Jul 29 14:02:30 8va Firewall[112]:  limit 1000 reached on entry 12300
Jul 29 14:03:23 8va servermgrd[77]: No requests in 300 seconds, shutting down
Jul 29 14:06:52 8va [0x0-0x1a01a].com.apple.systempreferences[661]: System Preferences(661,0x112b56000) malloc: *** auto malloc[661]: error: GC opera
Jul 29 14:07:47 8va mds[83]: (/)(Warning) IndexQuery in bool preIterate_FSI(SISearchCtx_FSI*):Throttling inefficient file system query
Jul 29 14:08:17: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul 29 14:09:27 8va UserEventAgent[31]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptivePublishState:1211 en1 - PreProbe
4480 Jul 29 14:09:27 8va configd[36]: network configuration changed.
```

**The "change" was me finally realizing the common factor, and shutting off the network.**

```
Jul 29 14:09:27 8va applepushserviced[287]: <APSCourier: 0x7f8e10d14b50>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x109c2dee0>: The operation couldn
Jul 29 14:09:27 8va configd[36]: network configuration changed.
Jul 29 14:09:27 8va applepushserviced[287]: <APSCourier: 0x7f8e10d14b50>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x7f8e10d40970>: The operation cou
Jul 29 14:09:42 8va applepushserviced[287]: <APSCourier: 0x7f8e10d14b50>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x109c4b190>: The operation couldn
Jul 29 14:10:12 8va applepushserviced[287]: <APSCourier: 0x7f8e10d14b50>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x109c5c730>: The operation couldn
Jul 29 14:11:12 8va applepushserviced[287]: <APSCourier: 0x7f8e10d14b50>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x109c21a70>: The operation couldn
Jul 29 14:13:12 8va applepushserviced[287]: <APSCourier: 0x7f8e10d14b50>: Stream error occurred for
```

**Crash. fsck and reading the serveradmin manpage in the empty void of single user mode.**

But turning off en1 or en0 or the unseen Bluetooth DUN that does not show up(!) in the gui. give one time to run this:

`<=(serveradmin list)  parallel serveradmin stop {}`

Got me out of it ( zsh FTW, and I prefer parallel to xargs ). Now, I tried that earlier, but did not have success.  Those were the services I wanted to stop, now the OS is no longer wrecking my hardware.

This was a totally clean install. To be fair, I installed the first time before the supplemental 10.6.8 patches, maybe its a finicky upgrade path. Who knows...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. The most bare bones install would be to erase the target volume and install Lion fresh. You could then download/install apps as you needed/wanted.

Comment: I actually did that. The default is to run a ton of stuff, and it's kernel panic'ing my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS isnt quite like Windows or Linux in that aspect, you cant run a "bare bones" version of Lion, nor a "Starter" version. Mac OS X Lion comes in a single version with all features.

As of minimum system requirements, Apple is pretty straight forward with that too. You need a mac with Intel Core 2 Duo at least. You also need 2GB of RAM, but I'd say most macs with a Core 2 Duo already have that covered. If not you can upgrade your memory.

To check your hardware click on the **Apple Menu**, select **About This Mac**, and then **More Info**.

As for apps, most apps just require you to be running a certain OS. Usually just games or heavy professional apps require minimum processor speeds/RAM memory.

For more info on Lion's Specs, go ahead and check:

http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html

Hope its useful. 
Kevin

Comment: "Mac OS X Lion comes in a single version with all features." Actually, it is much more "bare-bones" than it was before. Some features are downloaded as needed after the install now.

Comment: The only one I've heard of so far is XCode... which other features? I am planing to migrate to Lion soon and would like to know how much I'd have to download :/

Comment: printer drivers as well

Comment: Java is another thing that gets downloaded the first time you need it. Strangely it doesn't get triggered all the time. While typing java on the shell in Terminal.app or opening TV-Browser (an app for tv schedules) it worked fine, it failed when opening NetBeans. But hey, we're a 1.0 ;-)

Comment: and speech packs

Comment: I'd read the apple forums. It's shaky enough that don't want to tempt fate and run Chrome, or virtualbox :( The recovery partition is nice though.

Comment: Not surprising indeed. Apple does the same for extra iDVD themes and the first Garageband Jampack, which is free for download from within Garageband. After all, its lots of data you a user might never need in its whole life...

Problems with Chrome and virtualbox? D: